# Why minikube needs an explicit hypervisor

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, hypervisor

While running Minikube on mac, we need to specify vm-driver as it needs a hypervisor to run the virtual machine on which it would run the K8 Cluster.

Why can’t Minikube use the hypervisor of the host machine say mac as host machine already has a hypervisor by default ?

Answer (score 2):

Minikube has several [drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) that can plug into different virtualization backends.  That includes the ability to [run the cluster inside a single container](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/) (the current default) or to use the [Hyperkit](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperkit/) hypervisor (which Docker Desktop also uses).

If you want to use a different hypervisor by default, you can [configure minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#persistent-configuration) to do that:

```sh
minikube config set driver hyperkit
```

Answer (score 0):

Minikube creates a simple local kubernetes cluster having one Virtual Machine. Minikube needs a hypervisor such as VirtualBox or KVM to create this VM. Minikube started a virtual machine for us(based on our local environment), and a Kubernetes cluster is running in that VM i.e. all your nodes and services are running under the VM box! This is only case on **windows** or **osx**.

You can work on Minikube even without installing VirtualBox. Minikube also supports a `--driver=none` option that runs the Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver requires **Docker** and a **Linux** environment but not a hypervisor.